# Call a 'host' callback from a 'compiled assembly from source'

Tags: c#, system-codedom-compiler

I'm compiling code on-the-fly using `System.CodeDom.Compiler`. Everything inside the compiled source works well, whatever I'm putting inside this source. I know how to call my functions:

```
o = results.CompiledAssembly.CreateInstance("Foo.Bar");
MethodInfo mi = o.GetType().GetMethod("SayHello");
mi.Invoke(o, null);
```

But let's say I'm using a WebClient to retrieve a string asynchronously using WebClient.DownloadStringAsync. Or any other context where I want my compiled source to tell to the host "Hey, I got a nice string ready for you." For the example, I've used a WebBrowser. Basically, I know how to deal with each of the two instances: My hosting program and the compiled program, but I want my compiled program to communicate with the host. By the way, I'm not a super-experimented programmer, so no obvious method comes to my mind.

What I've tried:

1 . I don't really need to try it because it would work, but I could use a timer reading a strings stack or tasks queue inside the compiled source, but the purpose of my application is to have +- 60 scripts able to execute ponctual tasks, not continuous background processes, so it wouldn't be efficient on the CPU.

2 . I've passed the handler to the compiled source like if it was in the hosting app:

```
    //In the hosting app
    MethodInfo mi2 = o.GetType().GetMethod("attachCallbackToHost");
    mi2.Invoke(o2, new object[] { new WebBrowserNavigatedEventHandler (wb_navigated) });

    //... And the handler
    public static void wb_navigated(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
    {            
        string browserHtmlFromCompiledSource = ((WebBrowser)sender).DocumentText;
        MessageBox.Show(browserHtmlFromCompiledSource);
    }

    // Plain text from the compiled source code
    public void attachCallbackToHost(WebBrowserNavigatedEventHandler handlerFromTheHost)
    {
         wb.Navigated += handlerFromTheHost;
    }
```

And it did nothing.

3 . Maybe I could share a class or variable by passing it to the compiled assembly?

So, the question is either this or the other:

- How to watch efficiently for change inside a specific variable or property inside the compiled program?
- How to attach a callback to the host?

Comment: As for q3, you can use temp files and add the debug switch to the codedom compiler.

Comment: Why temp files and a debug switch? I want to either (1) be notified of variables change in the compiled source, or (2) have a callback called in the 'host' program. Right now, I'm searching on how the compiled program can access the host assembly, so I'd just follow the namespace to access my functions.

Comment: As per your answer, I seem to misunderstood the question (+1 for solving it and post the answer ;p)

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I didn't know what my real question should be. I had a goal however: communicate between a main application (host) and an assembly from a compiled-on-the-fly code. By searching with the keywords "codedom", "compiler", "assembly" and "access", I found a document mentioning these keywords. http://www.habitualcode.com/category/Scripting.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I got it: In order to access the host from the compiled source, the only thing required is to add the host assembly to the refered assemblies in the compiler parameters:

```
compilerParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
```

So no need for any special callback or INotifier.

Here's the full code that strictly answers my question and nothing more:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.CSharp;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.Reflection;

namespace MamaProgram
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string source =
           @"
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using MyMama = MamaProgram;              
namespace Baby
{
    public class Program
    {
        public WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();        

        public void navigateTo(string url)
        {
            wb.Navigated += wb_navigated;            
            wb.Navigate(url);            
        }

        public void wb_navigated(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
        {            
            MyMama.Form1.getResult(wb.DocumentText);            
        }
    }
}
            ";

            Dictionary<string, string> providerOptions = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    {"CompilerVersion", "v3.5"}
                };

            CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider(providerOptions);

            CompilerParameters compilerParams = new CompilerParameters
            {
                GenerateInMemory = true,
                GenerateExecutable = false,
                TreatWarningsAsErrors = false                
            };

            compilerParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
            compilerParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Data.dll");            
            compilerParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(typeof(System.Linq.Enumerable).Assembly.Location); // Trick to add assembly without knowing their name            
            compilerParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(typeof(System.ComponentModel.Component).Assembly.Location); // Trick to add assembly without knowing their name                        
            compilerParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Windows.Forms.dll");
            CompilerResults results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(compilerParams, source);

            if (results.Errors.Count != 0)
                throw new Exception("Compilation failed");

            object o = results.CompiledAssembly.CreateInstance("Baby.Program");
            MethodInfo mi2 = o.GetType().GetMethod("navigateTo");
            mi2.Invoke(o, new object[] { "http://www.google.com" });                        
        }

        public static void getResult(string result)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(result);
        }        
    }
}
```